# Divs shifting down when resize

Tags: css, html

Divs are shifting when I resize the browser. I looks fine at full screen but it drops all three headings down about 4 steps.  Even if I reduce the font size it is the same result.  m,nfm,.asnfmd,nf,mdan fm,.d

```
.wrapper {
    width: 497px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding: 0 5%; */
    display: block;
}

/*beginning css*/
.michael {
    color: #EEE8AA;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px #fff;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    /* left: 30%; */
    /* top: 0%; */
}

/*beginning css*/
.m {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*beginning css*/
.michael {
}

/*beginning css*/
.ringhead {
    position: relative;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* top: 4%; */
}

/*beginning css*/
.ring {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 60%;
}

/*beginning css*/
.christina {
    color: #EEE8AA;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    /* top: 0%; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
}

/*beginning css*/
.c {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 60%;
}

/*beginning css*/
body {
    background-image: url("Images/Top Banner.jpg"),url("Images/Middle `enter code here`Banner.jpg"),url("Images/Bottom Banner.png");
    background-size: 100% 10%,100% 15%,100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

/*beginning css*/
.weddingWebsite {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translateX(-55%) translateY(-55%);
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 60%;
}

/*beginning css*/
.wedding {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 60%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="michael">
        <p class="m">Michael</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ringhead"><img alt="Wedding Ring" class="ring" height="60" src=
    "../Images//gold.gif"></div>
    <div class="christina">
        <p class="c">Christina</p>
    </div>
    <div class="weddingWebsite"><img alt="Wedding Website" class="wedding"
    height="350" src="Wedding%20Website.jpg" width="350"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: m,nfm,.asnfmd,nf,mdan fm,.d?
Please provide HTML.

Comment: Please add your HTML. P.S why so many repetitive comments? "*/\*beginning css\*/*"

Comment: I couldn't understand how I was supposed to format. It was asking me a bunch of questions so I was just testing it to see if it would go through. Not sure what happened with my html. I thought we were to separate style and html.

Comment: <body>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="michael">
            <p class="m">Michael</p>
            </div> 
        <div class="ringhead">
            <img  src="Images/gold.gif" class="ring"  alt="Wedding Ring" `enter code here`width="100" height="60">
        </div>
        <div class="christina">
            <p class="c">Christina</p> 
        </div> 
        <div class="weddingWebsite">
            <img class="wedding" src="Images/Wedding Website.jpg" alt="Wedding Website" width="350" height="50">
        </div

Comment: https://w.trhou.se/054p1vz3tv here is my treeshouse workspace to have a look at what i'm talking about. thank you

Comment: Edit your question and add the HTML do it. And you can find websites that tidy your code like http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: @MichaelMorris headings are (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 & h6). You are using divs. When using percents `%` keep in mind that they are relative to their parent.

Comment: Thank you I do understand that but what difference does it make with the divs actually moving forward. I have also changed my wrapper width and height to a percentage without any difference. I understand what you mean about percentage or their relative parent. Just not seeing specifically what is the problem in this case. I've researched everything and cannot find a real answer. I have also posted a link to what it should look like with w.trhou.se/054p1vz3tv. there is a preview workspace in the upper right hand corner that gives an idea of what i'm talking about.